# How do I use sum()/average() for namedtuple in python?

Tags: python, numpy, namedtuple

```
from collections import namedtuple
Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
points = [Point(x=1.0, y=1.0), Point(x=2.0, y=2.0)]
```

I'd like to compute the average point out of `points` list, i.e. receive `Point(1.5, 1.5)` as a result:

```
point = average(points) # x = 1.5, y = 1.5
```

E.g. I know there's `np.average(points, axis=0)` if `points.shape` is `(N, 2)`, but I'd rather keep a named tuple instead.

Answer (score 3):

Calculate the average coordinate-wise:

```
import numpy as np
Point(np.average([p.x for p in points]),
      np.average([p.y for p in points]))
#Point(x=1.5, y=1.5)
```

Or, better, implicitly convert the list of points to a numpy array, get the average, and convert the result back to a Point

```
Point(*np.average(points, axis=0))
#Point(x=1.5, y=1.5)
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am missing something, but if you want to avoid `numpy` then you can do

```
>>> Point(sum(p.x for p in points)/len(points),sum(p.y for p in points)/len(points))
Point(x=1.5, y=1.5)
```

Seems a bit roundabout, though.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a cutsie way, using only Python built-ins:

```
In [1]: from collections import namedtuple
   ...: Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
   ...: points = [Point(x=1.0, y=1.0), Point(x=2.0, y=2.0)]
   ...:

In [2]: import statistics

In [3]: Point(*map(statistics.mean, zip(*points)))
Out[3]: Point(x=1.5, y=1.5)
```

Why are you using `numpy` to begin with? It doesn't make much sense here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a new subclass of `namedtuple` that has a `classmethod` to construct a new point from the average or sum of a sequence of points.

```
from collections import namedtuple


class Point(namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])):
    @classmethod
    def from_average(cls, points):
        from_sum = cls.from_sum(points)

        return cls(from_sum.x / len(points), from_sum.y / len(points))

    @classmethod
    def from_sum(cls, points):
        if not all(isinstance(p, cls) for p in points):
            raise ValueError('All items in sequence must be of type {}'.format(cls.__name__))

        x = sum(p.x for p in points)
        y = sum(p.y for p in points)

        return cls(x, y)


point_1 = Point(1.0, 1.0)
point_2 = Point(2.0, 2.0)

point_3 = Point.from_average([point_1, point_2])

point_3
# Point(x=1.5, y=1.5)

point_4 = Point.from_sum([point_1, point_2])

point_4
# Point(x=3.0, y=3.0)
```